# Trying to negate the end of the string

Tags: windows, string, python-3.x

In python, whenever I try to run the program, the part that has a backslash(negating the ending of the string) does not show up.

```
     father_name = ('\Please enter your Father\'s Name')
         print('')
     mother_name = ('\Please enter your Mother\'s Name')
         print ('')
```

When I run it on the shell, this happens:

```
    Please enter your Date of Birth Lehl

    Please enter your age 33



    Please enter your Physical Address No Idea

    Please enter your Phone Number 53525265345
```

The space in the middle is where the code should be but isn't

Comment: Uh, because you're printing blank lines? `print('')`

Comment: Why do you have a \ before `P` in Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask the user for input. Change the two lines to the following, and remove the print() statements that print nothing.

```
father_name = raw_input("Please enter your Father's Name: ")
mother_name = raw_input("Please enter your Mother's Name: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [input([prompt])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function if you want to be able to get input from user: If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

Be aware because you will always get a string. If you are expecting an int you have to convert it using int(). The same is for floats.

As you can take advantage of the different ways you have to write a string, you use `'` or `"` or `"""` or `'''` for delimiting the beginning and ending of a string. You can use `"` as delimiter for string instead of using `'` delimiters and escape characters `\'` for writing `'` chars in the middle of the string.

raw_input() function does not exist in python 3.x as a built-in function

```py
father_name = input("Please enter your Father's Name: ")
mother_name = input("Please enter your Mother's Name: ")


print("You entered as father name:", father_name)
print("You entered as mother name:", mother_name)
```